# Why this transformation matrix $A$ has $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ as Eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following transformation matrix:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 0 \\
-1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If I resolve to find the eigenvalues I get:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
A-\lambda I
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

which leads to:

$$
\lambda_1 = 1;
\lambda_2 = 4
$$

Now if I try to calculate the eigenvectors

For $\lambda_1$ I get:

$$
(A - 1 I)\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -x_1+3 x_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and for $\lambda_2$:

$$
(A - 1 I)\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3 x_1 \\ -x_1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I see (and can compute using a symbolic calculation program) that there are two eigenvectors:

$$
e1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
e2 = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

I can easily see why $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$.

But I am struggling to understand why $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector.

Could someone help me to understand why?

Comment: It is overkill. Check that $A.\binom{0}{1}$ has the form $\binom{0}{a}=a\binom{0}{1}$

Comment: I am learning how to calculate the eigenvectors in an Algebra course. I am aware on that the you can directly test that. Therefore I suppose it looks overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda_2$:

$$
(A - 1 I)\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3 x_1 \\ -x_1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow x_1=0\Rightarrow v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=x_2 \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

So your second eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is not an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_2=4$; it is an eigenvector for $\lambda_1=1$.

$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is the eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_2=4$, given that plugging in $x_1=3$, $x_2=1$ gives the zero vector in that calculation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made a rather unfortunate typo. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks that helps me to understand the underlying eigenvector calculation process.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward calculation shows that:
$$A\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
So $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=4$.